# Method call before HTTP session destroyed

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, guice, httpsession

I want to use SessionScope from Google Guice and before the session is destroyed I want to get data from SessionScoped object.

I try to use `HttpSessionListener.sessionDestroyed()` but at this moment i don't have session attributes.

Is any another method to check when the session attrubutes was destroyed?

Answer (score 1):

The [HttpSessionListener.sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html#sessionCreated-javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent-) parameter gives you access to the HttpSession using [HttpSessionEvent.getSession()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionEvent.html#getSession--).

You can then access the session attributes in the usual way.

Just be aware that there is often no associated HttpRequest when this is called.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. Obviously, you are right, but we may have misunderstood. When i use method which you suggest I have all session attribute, but Guice SessionScoped object is empty. That's why I want to find some method which is invoke before invalidate SessionScoped.

Comment: Perhaps Guice has it's own listener that gets called before yours?

Comment: So I try to find how Guice destroy Scopes. If I found any solution I will put it here. Thanks for help.